# Unable to access props data in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async.js

I'm unable **to access prop data**. When I open the [Vue DevTools tab](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) in Chrome the props *are* there, but I'm still not able to access them from the `created` or `mounted` hooks.

#### Parent component

```
 <Contradiction 
   :patient="patient" 
   @openForm="toggleFormTable">
 </Contradiction>
```

#### `Contradiction` component

```
name: "Contradiction",
  props: {
    patient: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      patient_id: this.patient.id,
    };
  },
  created() {
    console.log("created hook", this.patient); // shows null
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("mounted hook", this.patient); //shows null 
  },
```

I don't know why, but the `patient` prop does appear in the Vue tab in DevTools, but not when passing them to `console.log`:

[image: Vue DevTools extension screenshot]

Comment: Can you share a working ``fiddle`` of your code so it's easy to debug?

Comment: Is `patient` somehow async, like coming from an API or alike ? Did you tried with some hardcoded data at first ? Pretty sure it's just this kind of issue here.

Comment: its comming from api laravel end point

Comment: It's legit that it's not displaying it on the `mounted` lifecycle hook. It can be populated afterwards so not a big issue. But you cannot expect the component to have the data on mount if you do not wait for the data to come in. You could make a `v-if="Object.entries(patient).length"` on the `Contradiction` component if you want. This way, it will wait for you to have an object, then mount it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a project showing you how to achieve that you want to do: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-hugle-3c9cc?file=/src/App.vue

To explain more about my previous comment, we're using `v-if="Object.entries(patient).length"` to be sure that the data is here before loading anything at all.

```html
<contradiction
  v-if="Object.entries(patient).length"
  :patient="patient"
></contradiction>
```

Lazy-loading the component is also a good thing performance-wise:

```js
components: {
  Contradiction: () => import("./components/contradiction"),
},
```

Answer (score 4):

After clarifying from the comment that `patient` is not directly set in the parent component, you can define `patient_id` as a `computed` property:

```js
const Contradiction = Vue.component('contradiction', {
  template: '#contradiction',
  props: { patient: { type: Object } },
  computed: {
    patient_id() { if(this.patient) return this.patient.id; }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Contradiction },
  data() { return { patient: null } },
  mounted() { setTimeout(() => this.patient = {id:1}, 3000); },
  methods: {
    toggleFormTable() {}
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
     <Contradiction :patient="patient" @openForm="toggleFormTable"/>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="contradiction">
  <div>patient id: {{patient_id}}</div>
</template>
```

A better solution is to keep your implementation and only render the child component if the `prop` is set:

```js
const Contradiction = Vue.component('contradiction', {
  template: '#contradiction',
  props: { patient: { type: Object } },
  data() { return { patient_id: this.patient.id } }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Contradiction },
  data() { return { patient: null } },
  mounted() { setTimeout(() => this.patient = {id:1}, 3000); },
  methods: {
    toggleFormTable() {}
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
     <Contradiction v-if="patient" :patient="patient" @openForm="toggleFormTable"/>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="contradiction">
  <div>patient id: {{patient_id}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: I agree with Majed. also props should treat like a read-only data property